# flutter changing obsecure text according to the user choice

Tags: flutter

I am tyring to do a password textFormField with an eye icon so when the user pressing the icon the obsecure field will be change. But it doesn't seem's to work for me very well, if someone knows where is the problem in my code it will be very helpful. Thank you
this is my code:

```
class LogInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LogInPageState createState() => _LogInPageState();
}
class _LogInPageState extends State<LogInPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double defaultLoginSize = size.height - (size.height * 0.2);
    bool _secureText = true;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              width: size.width,
              height: defaultLoginSize,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Image.asset('assets/Image.png'),
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        // from now on it's the part of the code when I am trying to change                         
                        // the obsecure text
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _secureText = !_secureText;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Icon(_secureText
                              ? Icons.visibility_off
                              : Icons.visibility),
                        ),
                      ),
                      obscureText: _secureText,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move this line `bool _secureText = true;`
above the

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

and you are good to go.
the problem is that you are redrawing the widget and the variable was in the widget and was being recreated every time with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

when you use setState, flutter rerenders the widget and `build` function runs accordingly. So, as you have defined `bool _secureText=true` inside the build method, this variable always will be `true`. you should put

```
bool _secureText = true;
```

outside the build method.